# Drawing balls from an urn with specific labels and colors

Tags: probability

Balls are labeled 1, 2, and 3 and can be red green or blue. Balls are replaced after every draw and the probability of drawing each type of ball (1,2, or 3) is fixed but not known. Any ball with a 1 on it is half as likely to be green as the other colors. A ball with a 2 on it is half as likely to be red as the other colors. A ball labeled 3 is half as likely to be blue as the others colors. On the 20th draw, from the urn, you get a red ball with a number 2 on it for the first time. What is the best estimate for the probability of drawing a ball labeled 2 from the bag?

I think this problem has to do with conditional probability, something along the lines of given that a ball is labeled 2, finding the probability that it is red and starting there. Would appreciate if anyone could help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the probability of drawing a red 2 is $p$, which is the same for every draw since the balls are replaced. The number of draws we expect to make in total to get the first red 2 is $\frac{1}{p}$ (make sure you know why). If we infer $\frac{1}{p} = 20$ from the given experiment, then we estimate $p = \frac{1}{20}$.

Now, we the probability of getting a red 2 is the probability of getting a 2 (which is what we desire) times the probability that a ball is red given that it is a 2 (a conditional probability, like you mentioned). Since we are given that the probability that a 2 ball is red is half the probability that a 2 ball is green, and also half the probability that a 2 ball is blue, then the conditional probability "red given 2" is $\frac{1}{5}$ (since $\frac{1}{5} (1 + 2 + 2) = 1$). Therefore, the desired probability (of drawing a 2 regardless of color) is

$$\frac{\frac{1}{20}}{\frac{1}{5}} = \boxed{\frac{1}{4}}$$